# Clickwrap loading issue

Tags: javascript, docusignapi

I was trying to integrate Docusign clickwrap into my registration form. It always showing an error "Loading chunk 4 failed". Anyone has any experience with integrating Docusign Clickwrap?

https://www.screencast.com/t/9PLY8g20WR

```
<div id="ds-terms-of-service"></div>

<script src="https://demo.docusign.net/clickapi/sdk/latest/docusign-click.js"></script>
```

```js
<script>
    docuSignClick.Clickwrap.render({
        environment: 'https://demo.docusign.net',
        accountId: '3af8248c-9fc6-45a2-8bc5-2cfae36a74d6',
        clickwrapId: 'dd98b6ea-deb1-432f-ae09-4005bcfbaea4',
        clientUserId: '555'
    }, '#ds-terms-of-service');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks Lasantha for reporting this. We're working on this and should have a fix soon. I'll update this thread when I have more details.

Comment: Update: We're working on the fix and expect it be deployed next week. I'll make sure to confirm here.

Comment: this was fixed, not sure if you are still trying to do this, but should work fine now